# Automatically create folder on an FTP server in the context of an itext project

Tags: ftp, directory

We are using itext to create PDFs and we upload those PDFs to a FTP Server. Is it possible to automatically create a folder of the actual day on the FTP server and to put the PDFs created that day in that specific folder? We'd like have a list of folders with all the PDF of each specific day.

Comment: How do you do this? Does itext include a FTP client?

Comment: Creating a folder is outside the scope of iText. I'll edit your question because it's misleading. It's as if you want to create a folder with iText.

Comment: As @BrunoLowagie said, this has nothing to do with iText. This should probably be tagged something in the Java-land but I'm not sure what.